# Sharekit and facebook login conflicting

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, delegates

I have sharekit implemented in my app and it was working fine until I implement login with facebook in another View.

The sharekit asks me to add the following on the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    NSString* scheme = [url scheme];
    NSString* prefix = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb%@", SHKCONFIG(facebookAppId)];
    if ([scheme hasPrefix:prefix])
        return [SHKFacebook handleOpenURL:url];
    return YES;
}
```

The thing is that the facebook login api asks you do add the following code also on appdelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    return [SHKFacebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Now when I try to share something on Facebook, it asks for the permission and then nothing happens because it enters the second method.

I tried to track this instance variables "application", "sourceApplication", "url" and "annotation" but none of them gives me any clue on how to recognise if it comes from the login or share.

Any clues on that?

Comment: I managed to solve that by manipulating a boolean property, but I dont think its a nice solution. Anyway its working but I will wait for better solutions than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue and this is how to fix it:

- Find your `SHKFacebook.m` file
- find the following function:

```
(Facebook*)facebook 
{
  static Facebook *facebook=nil;
  @synchronized([SHKFacebook class]) {
    if (! facebook)
      facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:SHKCONFIG(facebookAppId)         urlSchemeSuffix:SHKCONFIG(facebookLocalAppId) andDelegate:nil];

  }
  return facebook;
}
```

This piece of code has to get the facebook instance like so (this is how i did it):

```
+ (Facebook*)facebook 
{
  static Facebook *facebook=nil;
  @synchronized([SHKFacebook class]) {
    if (! facebook)

    //Used for overwriting the SHKFacebook instance
      facebook = [[FacebookManager sharedManager]facebook];
  }
  return facebook;
}
```

This should solve all of your problems and even boosts performance of Sharekit as the user doesn't have to log in again. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the improvements Jonas ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue if you add facebookLocalAppId while using sharekit. I guess its the problem of Facebook SDK mainly.

Make sure tht localAppId is empty string and add  fb[AppId] in the url schemes of your info.plist.

It should work. Worked for me!

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/314394491907164?browse=search_4efdea61cc7cd8f83499042

Hope this helps!